# How to check if disabling sleep with SetThreadExecutionState fails?

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke

When disabling system sleep using the following line:

```
SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS | EXECUTION_STATE.ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED);
```

How can I tell that it worked? On one of my computers for instance, it doesn't work. The computer stil goes to sleep but there is no exception. If there is no exception, is there any other way to know that the call to SetThreadExecutionSTate failed?

Comment: If you call it a second time, the value returned should include the flags you set the first time around.  If it doesn't, something's gone wrong.

Comment: Just run `powercfg /requests` as Administrator and see the result.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The return value of `SetThreadExecutionState` is used to indicate success or failure. This is described in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa373208.aspx).

> **Return value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is the
>   previous thread execution state.
>
> If the function fails, the return
>   value is `NULL`.

The value of `NULL` is simply `0` so you can check for success by comparing the return value against `0`. So there will not be an exception when it fails. The return value will simply be `0`. Don't expect Windows API functions to raise exceptions to signal failure. They simply do not do that.

The p/invoke signature that you need, obtained from [pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/SetThreadExecutionState.html) is:

```
[FlagsAttribute]
public enum EXECUTION_STATE : uint
{
     ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED = 0x00000040,
     ES_CONTINUOUS = 0x80000000,
     ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED = 0x00000002,
     ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED = 0x00000001
     // Legacy flag, should not be used.
     // ES_USER_PRESENT = 0x00000004
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern EXECUTION_STATE SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE esFlags);
```

Then you can call it like this

```
bool succeeded = (SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS | 
    EXECUTION_STATE.ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED) != 0);
```

And if the call fails then raise an exception like this:

```
if (!succeeded)
    throw new Win32Exception();
```

Most likely your problem is that you are using `ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED`. I think you should be using `ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED`.

Answer (score 2):

The function returns a value to indicate whether the operation succeeded or not. If the return value is `NULL`, the operation failed. [(Source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The return value is `NULL` which is equivalent to `0`.

You should therefore capture the return value in a variable and check if it is zero:

```
uint result = SetThreadExecutionState(EXECUTION_STATE.ES_CONTINUOUS |
                                      EXECUTION_STATE.ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED);
if (result != 0)
{
    // Function failed...
}
```

Comment: The problem is that this method returns a struct (EXECUTION_STATE) and which can never be null: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.setthreadexecutionstate

Comment: To add to my answer, the `EXECUTION_STATE.ES_AWAYMODE_REQUIRED` is not supported by Windows XP or Windows Server 2003.

Comment: No, don't read the return value into an `object`. It needs to go into a 4 byte wide integer.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: any idea how you're supposed to distinguish between failure and a previous execution state of 0?

Comment: @Harry `0` is not a valid state. The documentation says: *This parameter can be **one or more** of the following values.* And all flags are non-zero.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: zero isn't a valid input value, but it isn't obvious that it isn't a valid output value.  If this is the first time SetThreadExecutionState is called, I'd have expected all the flags to be clear, but perhaps it just lies to us. :-)

Comment: @HarryJohnston If `0` is not a valid input state, then how could the state ever have been set to `0`? What's more, how could `0` be used to signal an error if `0` was the initial state?

Comment: @HarryJohnston The initial state is `ES_CONTINUOUS`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: OK, that almost makes sense.  I wish it was documented though.

Comment: @HarryJohnston `ES_CONTINUOUS` is always going to be in the returned state I expect. Read all the remarks. It is a bit of a weird one. The fact that 0 signals error means that it simply cannot be a valid state.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I realize that, but I was allowing for the possibility that the documentation was mistaken, given that it already says NULL when it should say 0. :-)

Comment: Well this sure clears up a lot of the misunderstanding. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Harry I'm sorry to be a pedant, but NULL is a macro that expands to 0

Comment: @John Regarding your update, the docs say NULL rather than null. And NULL is synonymous with 0.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for clearing that up! Learn something new every day :)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: yes, I realize that, but you're only supposed to use NULL when referring to pointer values.  This isn't a pointer value, so the documentation should say 0 rather than NULL.  The compiler won't know the difference, but that's no excuse!

Comment: Again regarding the edit, why do you mention null? It's not in the docs. And why talk about structs. There's no struct. It's a C enum.

Comment: @JohnWillemse: you may be (quite reasonably) wondering why NULL is equivalent to 0 instead of to `null`.  The answer is that the Win32 API is written in C, which doesn't *have* such a thing as `null`.  Even in C++ I believe the equivalent keyword, `nullptr`, was only introduced recently and is not yet universally supported.  It's a shame, but there you go.